# JavaScript Web Audio API - Audio Sampling Rate Issue on Android

Tags: javascript, audio, cross-platform

I am having a problem with the Web Audio API where the audio sampling rate is incorrect on an Android phone using Chrome, Opera and Edge browser, but it works fine using the Firefox browser.

I am recording the microphone into an array using Web Audio API as follows; where just snippets of my code have been included, as I cannot paste all of it, but this is just to show which functions I am using.

```
let audioContext;
dataArrayFft = new Float32Array(bufferLength);
audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)({ sampleRate:48000});
analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
const source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
source.connect(analyser);
```

I then call the following routine periodically (30Hz) to update my chart.js:

```
analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(dataArrayFft);
```

The code works fine on my PC using the Chrome browser and shows the full FFT spectrum up to 24kHz with a 48kHz sampling rate.

With my Android phone I point each of the browsers (Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Edge) to my laptop IP address (https://192.168.1.149:3000) to view the web page on my phone to test my app.

The following IMAGE 1 shows the app running in the Chrome browser on my Windows 10 laptop and it is working as expected.

[image: PC Chrome Browser running as expected]

The following IMAGES 2,3,4,5 show my Android phone viewing the web page on my laptop and as you can see for Chrome, Opera and Edge (IMAGES 2,3,5) the FFT spectrum rolls off at 8kHz but for Firefox (IMAGE 4) it shows the full spectrum as expected and I have confirmed it works by using a signal generator.

[image: Android Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Edge Browsers showing the problem]

I do not understand why it works as expected on Firefox but there is this 8kHz limit on the other browsers indicating the sampling rate is being limited to 16kHz? Any thoughts on what this problem could be caused by? It appears like there could be an issue with the Web Audio API in the affected browsers perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you need to turn the "echoCancellation" off in the web view. After finding this solution I then tried the following and I now get the full 24kHz FFT spectrum with a 48kHz sampling rate.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ 
audio: {
  optional: [
    { 
      echoCancellation: false,
    }
  ]
}})
```

Shown below is the code updated above with a 16kHz test tone:

[image: Wed Audio API FFT with 16kHz test tone]